# json_encode is no longer working since a server migration?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm currently in the process of migrating a site. And a script we used for generating a JSON string has suddenly stopped working. When viewing on the old server it seems to work fine.

CODE:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Stock");
$rows = array(); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  $rows[] = $row;
}
print json_encode($rows);
```

I'm wondering if anyone has heard of json_encode changes? The new server is PHP 5.6 and the old one is 5.3.

The output i'm getting is completely blank. But when I try to echo the `$row` It seems to show "Array". print_r displays the correct information, but not as I need it formatted.

Has anyone else come across this?

Comment: what's the output of json_encode, or is it has an error?

Comment: The output is blank. Or if I `print_r ($rows);` i get `Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 23 [title] => Cornwall 2 seater - 23 [date] => 0000-00-00 [content] => 18 - 40 - 20 - / Static - Endura 6727 Dolce Meteor - Highland Lime 225 - EX PHOTO - Cushion back [cost] => 995 [category] => Chairs ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 300 [titl...`

Comment: Stop using the **deprecated and as of PHP7 removed** `mysql_*` functions. Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared, Parameterized Queries.

Comment: I'd say check return value of `json_encode` and `json_last_error`.

Comment: Thanks @CharlotteDunois, the json_last_error pointed out a UTF8 issue. Obviously the new server is strict when it come to encoding.